# Python C extension: How to DECREF a C array of PyArrayObjects

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, numpy, python-c-api

I am creating some C extension code for python (example below).
Part of the function requires me to iterate arrays passed in as arguments, preform a calculation on each element, and return an array of the calculated values.

I am using `NpyIter_MultiNew` as it can iterate over multiple arrays and also create an appropriate array for the output.

`NpyIter_MultiNew` requires a C array of `PyArrayObject *` as input (here `op`).
`op` is filled from the output of `PyArray_FROM_OTF`.
These are new references and so I need to clean up at the end of the code.

**The question** I have is what do I need to `DECREF on? (i.e. what should go in the <>)

**Option 1:**

```
Py_XDECREF(op);
```

**Option 2:**

```
Py_XDECREF(op[0]);
Py_XDECREF(op[1]);
Py_XDECREF(op[2]);
```

**Option 3:**

```
Py_XDECREF(op[0]);
Py_XDECREF(op[1]);
Py_XDECREF(op[2]);
Py_XDECREF(op);
```

I think `Py_XDECREF(op[0])` might also be unnecessary.
I suspect that `op[0]` remains as `NULL` and is simply used as a flag to `NpyIter_MultiNew` to indicate the creation of a new array.
The new output array is recovered from `output = NpyIter_GetOperandArray(iter)[0];`

Note:
The references used in `PyObject * args_in[2]` are borrowed and so no `INCREF` or `DECREF` is required.

```
static PyObject *
UseArray(PyObject * args){

    PyObject * args_in[2];

    PyArrayObject * op[3] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
    npy_uint32 op_flags[3];

    PyArrayObject * output = NULL;

    // python inputs
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &args_in[0], &args_in[1])){
        goto fail;
    }

    // output array
    op[0] = NULL;
    op_flags[0] = NPY_ITER_WRITEONLY | NPY_ITER_ALLOCATE;

    // input array
    op[1] = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FROM_OTF(args_in[0], NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    op_flags[1] = NPY_ITER_READONLY;
    if (op[1] == NULL){
        goto fail;
    }
    op[2] = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FROM_OTF(args_in[1], NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    op_flags[2] = NPY_ITER_READONLY;
    if (op[2] == NULL){
        goto fail;
    }

    // iterate
    iter = NpyIter_MultiNew(3, op, NPY_ITER_EXTERNAL_LOOP, NPY_KEEPORDER, NPY_NO_CASTING, op_flags, NULL);
    <<iterator code>>

    // get output array
    output = NpyIter_GetOperandArray(iter)[0];
    Py_INCREF(output);

    if (NpyIter_Deallocate(iter) != NPY_SUCCEED){
        goto fail;
    }

    <<DECREF op>>

    return PyArray_Return(output);

    fail:
        <<DECREF op>>
        Py_XDECREF(output);
        return NULL;
}
```